# checking for stale sessions on the client side

Tags: django, client-server, django-sessions

in a django app, no signal generated when a session becomes invalid due to timeout

If I want to redirect my client to the login page after the session times out, is it a bad idea to have client side javascript function that periodically checks if it still has valid session? I don't see any other way, but I am totally new to web programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell no. Repeatedly polling the website would keep the session alive. Its a waste of bandwidth and overcomplicates things. The session is a server object so should be delt with there. I would recomend just checking on the pageload.

Comment: When the users session times out, there is no indication on the client side _until_ they click on a link, which if it requires authentication, will appear broken. So, then, just a redirect back to the main login page would be in order?

Comment: Yep. I havent used django specifically but in all the websites I have worked on there was a check on the master page on pageload. This would then redirect the browser to the login page if the session is null.